# How to apply static analysis rules after a certain commit

Tags: git, maven, static-analysis, software-quality

I've inhereted a large project which would need a lot of refactoring. I would like to add static analysis methods to have an eye on the quality. 
Since I dont want to have them applied atm/right away, I would like to know how to apply such rules (like pmd, findbugs, checkstyle...) in the maven cycle only for files which were created after a certain commit / timestamp.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot address any of the maven aspects, but there's a rather glaring problem with the general concept of "files *created after* some commit", which is this: every Git commit is a complete snapshot unto itself.  How will you tell which files were created when?

#### Ancestry testing

It's relatively easy to tell whether some commit (by hash ID or any other identifier) is a *descendant* of some other commit:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor 8ac9f31 33071ac
```

tells you whether the commit identified by `8ac9f31` "comes before" `33071ac` in the commit graph.  For this kind of thing it's probably wise to use a tag name (lightweight or annotated, it does not matter here from a usage standpoint).  Let's say you name this tag "enable-static-analysis", and wish to test whether some branch tip commit from the branch named `$branch` comes after that point:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor enable-static-analysis $branch; then
    ... run static analysis software ...
fi
```

For this particular purpose, the test is actually `≤` rather than `<`, i.e., if you repeat it with `8ac9f31 8ac9f31`, the answer will be "yes, `8ac9f31` is an ancestor of `8ac9f31`.  If you need an exclusive less-than property, you can add "and not equal", e.g.:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor enable-static-analysis $branch &&
    [ $(git rev-parse enable-static-analysis) != $(git rev-parse $branch) ]; then
```

or, provided the tag applies to an ordinary single-parent commit, use its own immediate ancestor in the test (this is less obvious but is a lot more efficient):

```
# We do not want to run this on a newly created branch whose
# current commit *is* the static-analysis enablement commit,
# hence the hat suffix:
if git merge-base --is-ancestor enable-static-analysis^ $branch
```

But that only gets you the "commit comes after" part, not the "files created since" part.

#### Snapshot issues

Fundamentally, the problem is that you have no way of knowing whether file `path/to/file.ext` in commit `$descendant` bears any relationship to file `path/to/file.ext` in commit `$ancestor`.  Moreover, what if `path/to/file.ext` in `$descendant` got there by being renamed, with or without any modification, from `some/other/file.ext` or `path/to/othername.otherext`?

Neither, really, does Git.  What Git does for `git diff` purposes is, by default, to *assume* that those two files are the "same entity" if they have the same path name, unless you use the `-B` flag to `git diff`.  Meanwhile, if some path name is *missing* in the ancestor, and some other path name is *new* in the descendant, that path-pair becomes a candidate for *rename detection*.  Rename detection works based on a similarity index.  If you add the `-B` option, two files with the *same* path name, in the two commits in question, are "broken apart" if this same similarity index falls below some threshold.  If rename detection is turned on, any files that are unpaired—including any resulting from pair-breaking due to `-B`—are run through the rename similarity test, and if they pass, the two paths are joined as a "renamed file".  You can find Git's decision on this by running `git diff-tree -r -M --name-status $ancestor $descendant` and parsing its output (if doing this programmatically, consider adding `-z` as well).

It's up to you whether to be this fancy, or to be fancy in a different way (possible ways are limited mainly by your imagination, and how much compute resource you are willing to throw at this; maven itself may offer more ways, especially if it has "manifest" files).  Or you can use the simple, but obviously somewhat defective, "did the path name exist before" test to decide if `path/to/file.ext` was "created since" the ancestor commit:

```
oldhash=$(git rev-parse --verify --quiet $ancestor:$path)
```

If this succeeds, the path did exist before, and you now have the blob's hash ID in `$oldhash`.  This will let you tell if the file has changed at all: if so, its new hash from parsing `$descendant:$path` as a revision specifier will differ.

(Besides the rename issue, this clearly fails in the case where `$path` existed in `$ancestor`, but was removed entirely in some intermediate commit, then created anew in or before the descendant commit.  This case *is* detectable, by walking through every commit in the ancestry path from `git rev-list --ancestry-path $ancestor..$descendant, except that you would need to take care at any merges in case of branch-and-merge structures in the ancestry-path DAGlet (subgraph).  It's probably not worth doing: Git's similarity testing is likely to be more reliable.)

If you put all this together, you will probably end up wanting to do:

```
git diff-tree -r --name-status $ancestor $descendant
```

perhaps with some additional `--diff-filter` and/or `-M` and/or `-B` flags.  Any files with status `A` (added) would be ones to analyze.  Files with status `M` might also be good candidates: someone touched them, so it is time to make them pass static analysis.